# Core Data multithread store relations

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios5, core-data, entity-relationship

my problem is very strange and I am asking for help. I want to explain to you how my system works. I have two problem with this.

I am making application which have two tables. I am using core data. Tables are ***Categories*** and ***Products***, in core data I have established one to many relationship ***Category*** can have multiple ***Products***, ***Product*** can hove one ***Categroy***.

Here is basic schema

```
Category {
  site_id
  name
  allProducts ->> Product
}

Product {
  site_id
  name
  category -> Category
}
```

- this is simplefied model products and catwegories has more properties

In that application I have updating process, and that process works in backgournd thread. I have created context for that thread and all changes I am storing in that context.

All caluclation I am executing in background thread in

```
[context performBlock:^{
  // all my operations for updating storing categories and products
}]
```

**This is flow of updateding process**

1. From server get JSON with categories data
2. From server get JSON with products data
3. From server get JSON with info which category has which products `array((category_site_id > array(product_site_id1, product_site_id2...))`
4. Pass through categories JSON and store category entity, I am getting name and site_id from JSON and create entity and set these properties
5. Pass through products JSON and create product entity and set name and store_id from properties from JSON

**Then main part**

1. Now I need to connect product to categories based on JSON geted in step 3 and here is a problem.

I am going foreach category from JSON and get all products site_id as NSArray, I am using fetch request with predicate and IN criteria to get all **products** entities from context which have site_id IN array. But I always got zero results. That is strange because I am calling fetch results on context in background thread and I also updated that context in step 3 and 4.

Then I try next thing, before step 6 I `[context save:&error]` and added sleep about 30 secconds and when after that program run into step 6 all work funtastic my fetch results get products with predicate with IN criteria. That is a my first problem if you understand me, I can not get products by IDs I need to wait about 30 sec to context store to SQLLiteDB it is very strange. Also this is strange because when I want to get category with fetch request by id I can get it without problems ***(maybe that it is because step 5 takes about one minute).***

My next problem is when I wait that 30 sec and then passing trought categories. Based on category site_id I get Category entity from context and also in step 6 I get all products base on product site_ids geted by JSON and fetch request and now I want to add products to category and I call next

[category setAllProducts:results] // results are NSSet of product, category is entity object

NSError *error = nil;
[context save:&error];

and I do that foreach categroy (geted in step 3 from server in JSON format)

when all is done I can not see products in categroies on UI I am also waiting some time to all data be stored in DB but nothing heppenes,

AND THEN WHEN I STOP APPLICATION AND RUN IT AGAIN I CAN SEE PRODUCTS IN CATEGORIES :(

very strange problem please help me I do not know where I am a wrong. I can post parts of code, code is not small and I asking for help based on description of process.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My understanding is that you are using child contexts. Child contexts are affected by many (**many!**) bugs you have to deal with.

Pretty good article about that topic here:

http://wbyoung.tumblr.com/post/27851725562/core-data-growing-pains

My advice on that matter is to use a context directly connected to the store coordinator, not a child context. Everything will work fine using such a setup. You can use a private queue context of course.

Comment: Yes when I create conext in thread something like this `NSManagedObjectContext *asyncContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];` I am added parent context `asyncContext.parentContext = mainDocument.managetContextObject`, somehitnk like that, probably that is a problem.

Comment: I will try today with store coordinator but I do not know how to do that, can you give me some example or tutorial. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi I have used store coordinator and now all work correctly and I not need to wait data to store to db and all data is there after updating all ui elements are reloaded correctly. Thank you very much again!